# Flutter show close icon after tapping search Icon

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I'm working on a Flutter app where I have a search functionality. I want to show a close icon, after tapping the search icon when results are founded , indicating that the user can clear the search text. And after clearing the searchtext, the searchIcon must appears again for futher searching.

My code now:

```
class _OverViewState extends State<OverView> {
  OverViewController overViewController = OverViewController();
  List<House> houses = []; // Store all houses
  String searchText = '';
  bool isLoading = true; // Add a new isLoading flag
  


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getHouses();
    checkLocationPermission();
  }

  // Fetch houses and filter them based on the searchText
  void getHouses() async {
    await overViewController.fetchSortedHouses();
    houses = overViewController.filterHouses(searchText);
    isLoading = false; // Set isLoading to false when houses are fetched

    setState(() {}); //this will trigger the call to rebuild UI
  }

  void filterHouses() {
    
    List<House> filteredHouses = overViewController.filterHouses(searchText);

    setState(() {
      houses = filteredHouses;
    });
  }

  void checkLocationPermission() async {
    final bool locationAccessGranted =
        await overViewController.authorizeLocationAccess();

    if (locationAccessGranted) {
      await overViewController.getCurrentLocation();
      getHouses(); // Refresh the list of houses based on the updated location
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      body: Container(
        color: const Color(0xFFEBEBEB),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color(0x33000000),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                searchText = value;
                              });
                            },
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Search for something',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0x66000000),
                              ),
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => filterHouses(),
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            'assets/icons/ic_search.svg',
                            width: 25,
                            height: 25,
                            color: Color(0x66000000),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

I want really to tap it for searching and clearing searchText and not on Onchange. I would appreciate any guidance on how to achieve the desired behavior or some example code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchField extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SearchField> createState() => _SearchFieldState();
}

class _SearchFieldState extends State<SearchField> {
  bool isCloseIcon = false;
  final TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0x33000000),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: searchController,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          if (!isCloseIcon && value.isNotEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                              isCloseIcon = true;
                            });
                          }
                          if (isCloseIcon && value.isEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                              isCloseIcon = false;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Search for something',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0x66000000),
                          ),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        if (!isCloseIcon) {
                          filterHouses();
                        }
                        if (isCloseIcon) {
                          searchController.clear();
                          setState(() {
                            isCloseIcon = false;
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      child: Icon(isCloseIcon ? Icons.close : Icons.search),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void filterHouses() {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro i will try it. I will let you know when its working or not! Appreciate !

Comment: thx bro this is very usefull. I did adjust somethings playing with the boolean but i have figured ! Thanks mate!